# How to concatenate datafiles in a loop?

Tags: python, iteration, concatenation

Here is the script and I would like to put it in a loop as the number of files (n) will change every time:

```
coef = 1000
data1 = myoriginaldata + coef
data2 = data1 + coef
data3 = data2 + coef
.
.
.
# and in general
data[n] = data[n-1]+coef
```

and then I would like to concatenate all like:

```
pd.concat([myoriginaldata,data1,data2,...,data[n])
```

Can someone please advise how I can put this script in a loop?

Comment: What does `myoriginaldata` look like? Also, are you wanting to add `1000` to each value in your dataset each iteration?

Comment: myoriginaldata is the main data set with only one column as a counter and I'm going to add a constant value to my dataset and of course in a loop for multiple data sets.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all responses. Its now sorted. @Myroslav Hryshyn approach works slightly better for my case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do smth like:

```
result_list = [myoriginaldata]
for i in range(n):
    new_result = result_list[n] + coef
    result_list.apend(new_result)

pd.concat(result_list)
```

Comment: @SoheilKoushan Don't hesitate to upvote my answer =)

Answer (score 0):

```
coef = 1000
for i in range (1,coef):
    if i == 1:
        data[i] = myoriginaldata + coef
    else:
        data[i] = data[i-1] + coef
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one line using generator comprehension:

```
pd.concat((df1+coef*i for i in range(0,n+1)),ignore_index=True)
```

Output where `coef = 1000`, `n = 5`, and `df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('CD'))`:

```
    C       D
0   2       6
1   7       8
2   1002    1006
3   1007    1008
4   2002    2006
5   2007    2008
6   3002    3006
7   3007    3008
8   4002    4006
9   4007    4008
10  5002    5006
11  5007    5008
```